# How to manipulate combination output?

Tags: r, combinations

I have a vector `vars` which has six elements:

```
vars <- c("ac", "fv", "vs", "v2", "ms", "yv")
```

To combine the elements randomly I use `combn`

```
a <- do.call(paste, c(data.frame(t(combn(vars, 5)))))
```

The output looks like this

```
a
[1] "ac fv vs v2 ms"
[2] "ac fv vs v2 yv"
[3] "ac fv vs ms yv"
[4] "ac vs v2 ms yv"
[5] "fv vs v2 ms yv"
```

Now I want to put a "+" between the elements that the output looks like this:

```
a
[1] "ac+fv+vs+v2+ms"
[2] "ac+fv+vs+v2+yv"
[3] "ac+fv+vs+ms+yv"
[4] "ac+vs+v2+ms+yv"
[5] "fv+vs+v2+ms+yv"
```

I tried to replace the spaces between the elements with `gsub` but this doesn't work because there are no spaces. Any comment is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be much easier if you use the `FUN` argument in `combn`.  And the `collapse` argument in `paste` is perfect for inserting the `+` signs.

For a data frame result, you can do

```
data.frame(a = combn(vars, 5, FUN = paste, collapse = "+"))
#                a
# 1 ac+fv+vs+v2+ms
# 2 ac+fv+vs+v2+yv
# 3 ac+fv+vs+ms+yv
# 4 ac+fv+v2+ms+yv
# 5 ac+vs+v2+ms+yv
# 6 fv+vs+v2+ms+yv
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `do.call` do:

```
apply(data.frame(t(combn(vars, 5))), 1, paste, collapse="+")
```

Comment: +1, I guess you don't need `data.frame` here or perhaps a `data.frame` outside the `apply` would make some difference in the output format.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why you were not able to replace using `gsub`

```
 gsub(" ", "+", a)
 #[1] "ac+fv+vs+v2+ms" "ac+fv+vs+v2+yv" "ac+fv+vs+ms+yv" "ac+fv+v2+ms+yv"
 #[5] "ac+vs+v2+ms+yv" "fv+vs+v2+ms+yv"
```

Comment: Because there are no spaces between the elements, I guess.

Comment: @Thomas Based on the example you showed, I am able to replace it.  May be you tried `paste0` instead of `paste`